# Is it safe to delete files from my Dropbox account that were shared by someone else?

Tags: dropbox

A friend shared a bunch of photos with me via my DropBox account and now I want to delete them. The files are showing as "shared" in my account.

I'm concerned that if I delete the files from my account they'll also be deleted from his. As they count towards my usage it appears that they are mine to delete, but I didn't create them in the first place.

Is it safe for me to delete the files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that the files were not mine to delete after all.

Right clicking on the folder brings up the context menu - the first option of which is **Shared Folder Options**. Clicking on that option shows the following dialog:

[image: Dropbox folder sharing options]

In this case I'm the only member on the list so it's safe to delete the folder. In the other folder there were more names on the list - the person who shared the folder in the first place and others. In this case it would **NOT** be safe to delete the folder as it would delete it for everyone else as well.

The correct action here is to click on the "Leave folder" option. You get the option to keep the files on your computer and then on OK your usage is reduced by the size of the files that were in the folder.

Comment: yes, I learnt this the hard way

Comment: this answer should have "it would NOT be safe ...the correct action here is..." and move to the top of the post. It's the most important part, and most directly corresponds to the question title. As now appearing after the image it looks almost like a footnote, of perhaps little importance.

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that **Dropbox does keep a backup copy** of the files (30 days for free accounts), so even in case they are deleted **anyone can still restore them**.